# Проблема с передачей данных из потока в MainActivity при повороте Android устройства

Tags: android, многопоточность

При разработке приложения под Android столкнулся с тривиальной задачей, на которую не могу найти простой ответ. В MainActivity запускается поток, который может выполняться относительно длительное время (в моей задаче подключение через bluetooth), по завершению поток должен как-то сообщить MainActivity, что он закончил работу. Я упростил код задачи до минимума, чтобы легко обрисовать проблему.
В MainActivity имеется единственная кнопка. При старте приложения переменная connectionEnabled = true (кнопка активна). При нажатии на кнопку блокируется ее нажатие (connectionEnabled = false), после чего запускается поток, в котором отсчитывается 5 секунд, после чего через метод runOnUiThread выбрасывается сообщение и восстанавливается исходное состояние кнопки. Все очень просто:

```
'''
package com.km.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean connectionEnabled;

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("connection", connectionEnabled);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            connectionEnabled = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("connection");
        } else {
            connectionEnabled = true;
        }
        enableConnect(connectionEnabled);
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View view) {
        // На время, пока идет подключение, блокируем кнопку
        enableConnect(false);
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            runOnUiThread(connectionFailed);
        }).start();
    }

    Runnable connectionFailed = new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            enableConnect(true);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    private void enableConnect(boolean enable) {
        connectionEnabled = enable;
        Button btnConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConnect);
        btnConnect.setEnabled(enable);
    }
}
'''
```

Если в процессе выполнения потока повернуть мобильник, по завершении потока Toast выбрасывается, но кнопка остается заблокированной. Как я понимаю, при повороте происходит уничтожение и создание активности заново, но запущенный процесс почему-то запускает метод из  предыдущего экземпляра активности (не уничтоженного, а все еще остающегося в памяти!). Таким образом runOnUiThread не запускает метод актуального UiThread, а того, что был на момент создания потока. Вопрос: как решить эту простую задачу, передав информацию из потока в текущую MainActivity, если за время выполнения потока она может жить своей жизнью? Я пробовал передавать сообщения через Handler - результат такой же. Есть какой-то относительно простой способ решения или подразумеваются пляски с бубном?

Comment: Запуск потоков в активити сравним с запретом поворота в манифесте. И то и другое делать не стоит, но в качестве простого варианта может сгодится.  
Правильно делать через ViewModel, в которой хранится состояние, переживающее смену конфигурации. И далее из view model'и вызываются методы repository, которые возвращают данные из локального и или удаленного хранилища. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Comment: Вам поможет Loader, еще вариант - это сервис, еще вариант это отсылать широковещательное сообщение из потока, а активность его должна ловить.

Comment: Конкретно в вашем примере кода проблема в том, что запущенный поток будет пытаться отравить результат в активити которой уже нет (`runOnUiThread()` - метод активити). А о новой он узнать никак не может.

Comment: Поэтому совет простой - запускайте потоки вне контекста активити. В случае Bluetooth это либо сервис, либо Application.

Answer (score 0):

Отличное решение - использование широковещательного сообщения. Вот рабочий код:

```
'''
package com.km.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean connectionEnabled;

    private class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            runOnUiThread(connectionFailed);
        }
    }
    private MyBroadcastReceiver receiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
    private final String MESSAGE_CONNECTION_FAILED = "com.km.myapplication.CONNECTION_FAILED";

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("connection", connectionEnabled);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(MESSAGE_CONNECTION_FAILED));
    }

    @Override
    protected  void onPause() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            connectionEnabled = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("connection");
        } else {
            connectionEnabled = true;
        }
        enableConnect(connectionEnabled);

    }

    public void onButtonClick(View view) {
        // На время, пока идет подключение, блокируем кнопку
        enableConnect(false);
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            Intent intent = new Intent(MESSAGE_CONNECTION_FAILED);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
            //runOnUiThread(connectionFailed);
        });
        t.start();
    }

    Runnable connectionFailed = new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            enableConnect(true);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    private void enableConnect(boolean enable) {
        connectionEnabled = enable;
        Button btnConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConnect);
        btnConnect.setEnabled(enable);
    }
}
'''
```

В манифест добавлять ничего не надо.

Comment: Если свернуть приложение, то можно потерять сообщение. Не надо так делать.

Comment: Нужно регистрировать ресивер в событии onResume, сбрасывать регистрацию в onPause, как в этом коде. Только при таком подходе (и только так!) сообщение не потеряется при сворачивании приложения. Я проверил.

Comment: Как только вы сделали unregisterReceiver вы больше не получаете события. Нажали кнопку, свернули приложение подождали пять секунд, открыли приложение, статус так и будет connectionEnabled =false

Comment: Согласен.  Переделал код так: ресивер регистрируется в onCreate, отключается в onDestroy. И все работает как надо. Есть только одно но: если нажать кнопку, свернуть приложение, повернуть экран, дождаться выполнения потока, развернуть приложение - кнопка останется неактивной. Мне кажется, сохранять вспомогательные переменные в SaveInstanceState - не очень хорошая идея. Хорошо работает метод, при котором создается кастомный класс Application со своими переменными (фактически это глобальные переменные приложения). Но многие пишут, что это плохой путь. Что делать?